# Reading an Access DB with Jackcess library

Tags: java, netbeans, jackcess

this is my first time trying to do this... I am trying to just get a link to my DB and then display a table to see if the link is established. For some reason it just doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
package dbtest;
import java.io.*;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*; 
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class DbTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
     Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("Users\\ou_snaaksie\\NetBeansProjects\\dbTest\\MOVIES.mdb"));
     Table tblMOVIES = db.getTable("tblMOVIES");
        System.out.println(tblMOVIES.toString());


    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {Logger.getLogger(DbTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}

    }

}
```

And the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<clinit>(DatabaseImpl.java:91)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:170)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:193)
at dbtest.DbTest.main(DbTest.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that your project is missing `commons-logging`. As mentioned on Jackcess' [dependencies page](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html), in addition to the Jackcess .jar file you also need

- [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) v2.x (commons-lang-2.4.jar, or newer), and
- [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) (commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, or newer)

So, the Libraries folder in your NetBeans project should look something like this:

[image: Libraries.png]